# How can I make a JS slideshow with multiple images?

Tags: javascript

I currently have a 'functional' JS slideshow/carousel, but I am having an issue where I have a very wide slideshow container, and it is only showing one thumbnail at a time.

I would like to create a set of 8 default images that are shown at once.  If you click the arrow I would like it to show 8 more images.  In addition to this, I would like it to tell you the images you are viewing. (ex: Showing images 1 through 8)

This area circled in red is my whole slide container

[image]

But you can see it only shows one image and an arrow.

How can I make this show more images at a time, and proceed as necessary?

```
 <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
      <?php foreach ($imageResult as $im): ?>
        <?php if($im['type'] == 'content'){?>

          <img class="mySlides" src="<?php echo $im['url']; ?>" style="max-width:200px; max-height:200px;">

        <?php } ?>
     <?php endforeach?>
    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
  </div>

 <script>
 var slideIndex = 1;
 showDivs(slideIndex);

 function plusDivs(n) {
 showDivs(slideIndex += n);
 }

 function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: what's the red bar on the side?  the 2nd image?  if so, it would appear you have a margin on `img` or `.mySlides` or something similar pushing the images apart. secondly, you're setting display to 'block', which means "gimme a separate line".  unless you have a `float`.  i'd check your CSS -- it's something to do with whitespace + font size, margin, etc.

Comment: That red line is actually a div in the background but I didn't crop it. If I remove the JS then the images go down in a vertical line

Comment: @oooyaya I can change it to inline-block but I need to change the actual formula in order to show/move more than one at a timw

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
 <script>
 var slideIndex = 1; // This may skip the first image... maybe change to 0?

 showDivs(slideIndex);

 function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
 }

 function showDivs(n) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}

  // Assuming we can show the next 8 images...
  var maxCount = slideIndex + 8;

  // However, there may not be 8 more images... 
  if(slideIndex + 8 > x.length){
    maxCount = slideIndex + (x.length - slideIndex);
  }

  // Hide all images...
  x.style.display = "none";   

  // Show the next 8 or so images...
  for (i = slideIndex; i <= maxCount; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "block";
  } 
 }
 </script>
```